# What are the core properties of a UIElement in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uielement

According to MSDN: 
A child `UIElement` begins the layout process by first having its core properties measured.

Sizing properties defined on `FrameworkElement` are evaluated, such as Width, Height, and Margin.

Panel -specific logic is applied, such as Dock direction or stacking Orientation.

Content is arranged after all children have been measured.

The Children collection is drawn on the screen.

The process is invoked again if additional Children are added to the collection, a LayoutTransform is applied, or the UpdateLayout method is called.

But what exactly are the core properties of a `UIElement`?

Answer (score 4):

The method it's speaking of is `MeasureCore`, and on the literal `UIElement` class it's implemented like this:

```
protected virtual Size MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
{
    return new Size(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

so as you can see it in fact does nothing on the `UIElement`. However, on the `FrameworkElement` it is implemented like this:

```
protected sealed override Size MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
{
    bool useLayoutRounding = this.UseLayoutRounding;
    if (useLayoutRounding && !base.CheckFlagsAnd(VisualFlags.UseLayoutRounding))
    {
        base.SetFlags(true, VisualFlags.UseLayoutRounding);
    }
    this.ApplyTemplate();
    if (this.BypassLayoutPolicies)
    {
        return this.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
    Thickness margin = this.Margin;
    double num = margin.Left + margin.Right;
    double num2 = margin.Top + margin.Bottom;
    if (useLayoutRounding && this is ScrollContentPresenter)
    {
        num = UIElement.RoundLayoutValue(num, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleX);
        num2 = UIElement.RoundLayoutValue(num2, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleY);
    }
    Size size = new Size(Math.Max(availableSize.Width - num, 0.0), Math.Max(availableSize.Height - num2, 0.0));
    FrameworkElement.MinMax minMax = new FrameworkElement.MinMax(this);
    FrameworkElement.LayoutTransformData layoutTransformData = FrameworkElement.LayoutTransformDataField.GetValue(this);
    Transform layoutTransform = this.LayoutTransform;
    if (layoutTransform != null && !layoutTransform.IsIdentity)
    {
        if (layoutTransformData == null)
        {
            layoutTransformData = new FrameworkElement.LayoutTransformData();
            FrameworkElement.LayoutTransformDataField.SetValue(this, layoutTransformData);
        }
        layoutTransformData.CreateTransformSnapshot(layoutTransform);
        layoutTransformData.UntransformedDS = default(Size);
        if (useLayoutRounding)
        {
            layoutTransformData.TransformedUnroundedDS = default(Size);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (layoutTransformData != null)
        {
            layoutTransformData = null;
            FrameworkElement.LayoutTransformDataField.ClearValue(this);
        }
    }
    if (layoutTransformData != null)
    {
        size = this.FindMaximalAreaLocalSpaceRect(layoutTransformData.Transform, size);
    }
    size.Width = Math.Max(minMax.minWidth, Math.Min(size.Width, minMax.maxWidth));
    size.Height = Math.Max(minMax.minHeight, Math.Min(size.Height, minMax.maxHeight));
    if (useLayoutRounding)
    {
        size = UIElement.RoundLayoutSize(size, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleX, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleY);
    }
    Size size2 = this.MeasureOverride(size);
    size2 = new Size(Math.Max(size2.Width, minMax.minWidth), Math.Max(size2.Height, minMax.minHeight));
    Size size3 = size2;
    if (layoutTransformData != null)
    {
        layoutTransformData.UntransformedDS = size3;
        Rect rect = Rect.Transform(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, size3.Width, size3.Height), layoutTransformData.Transform.Value);
        size3.Width = rect.Width;
        size3.Height = rect.Height;
    }
    bool flag = false;
    if (size2.Width > minMax.maxWidth)
    {
        size2.Width = minMax.maxWidth;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (size2.Height > minMax.maxHeight)
    {
        size2.Height = minMax.maxHeight;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (layoutTransformData != null)
    {
        Rect rect2 = Rect.Transform(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, size2.Width, size2.Height), layoutTransformData.Transform.Value);
        size2.Width = rect2.Width;
        size2.Height = rect2.Height;
    }
    double num3 = size2.Width + num;
    double num4 = size2.Height + num2;
    if (num3 > availableSize.Width)
    {
        num3 = availableSize.Width;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (num4 > availableSize.Height)
    {
        num4 = availableSize.Height;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (layoutTransformData != null)
    {
        layoutTransformData.TransformedUnroundedDS = new Size(Math.Max(0.0, num3), Math.Max(0.0, num4));
    }
    if (useLayoutRounding)
    {
        num3 = UIElement.RoundLayoutValue(num3, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleX);
        num4 = UIElement.RoundLayoutValue(num4, FrameworkElement.DpiScaleY);
    }
    SizeBox sizeBox = FrameworkElement.UnclippedDesiredSizeField.GetValue(this);
    if (flag || num3 < 0.0 || num4 < 0.0)
    {
        if (sizeBox == null)
        {
            sizeBox = new SizeBox(size3);
            FrameworkElement.UnclippedDesiredSizeField.SetValue(this, sizeBox);
        }
        else
        {
            sizeBox.Width = size3.Width;
            sizeBox.Height = size3.Height;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (sizeBox != null)
        {
            FrameworkElement.UnclippedDesiredSizeField.ClearValue(this);
        }
    }
    return new Size(Math.Max(0.0, num3), Math.Max(0.0, num4));
}
```

I know that's a lot of code to paste, but I did it to make a point. It's complicated -very complicated -and that method can be overriden by inheriters to boot.

In this code example you see things like `Width`, `Height`, `Margin`, and much more used to measure its core.

Comment: cool! btw, how did you get all that code? it seems useful to be able to see everything at times

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet, I just decompiled the .NET source with ILSpy.

Answer (score 3):

> But what exactly are the core properties of a UIElement?

In this context, the "core properties" would be the properties that effect layout, such as [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx), [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx), and the [VisualTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualtransform.aspx), as these will all impact the layout process of the item or its children.

Comment: ah i have one other question. Does rendering occur like this? measure, arrange, then render? what causes render to be called?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet Rendering is handled via DirectX - for (a lot) more info, see: http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the list the core properties of `UIElement` in WPF at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx

hope this explains you...